# Java ServiceLoader: no error, but also no implementations found

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out the ServiceLoader of Java.
I set up a VERY basic test-implementation:

```
public class BaseThingy {

public BaseThingy(){

    Iterator<WriteService> iter = ServiceLoader.load(WriteService.class).iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        WriteService plugin = iter.next();
        System.out.print(plugin.getText());
    }

}}
```

Interface:

```
public interface WriteService {

String getText();}
```

Now, as far as I understood things, I write an implementation, and put the implementing class (with no further files or manifest??) into a jar.

The project itself requires a file: META-INF\services\experimental.plugin.WriteService

In this file, I write the full name of the implementation (in my case. that would be experimental.plugin.WriteHello).

Now, I am working within Intellij as IDE.
Where should I put the file, and where should I put the jar with the implementing class?
I am not getting any errors, but neither is ANY implementation being found.
Or does the jar-file need anything additional after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The META-INF/services/experimental.plugin.WriteService must be in the classpath as well as the JAR with the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, it was the META-INF missing from the classpath :)